# Visualising Audio - How to do it

Tags: audio, video, graphics

I want to know how this: https://youtu.be/aFXcQvdAe08 was done.

Any ideas​ how this was created?

Comment: You'll need to read up on stuff like [this](https://www.airtightinteractive.com/2013/10/making-audio-reactive-visuals/) and google for more audio reactive visuals

Answer (score -1):

In really high level terms, I think it could happen like this:

1. The entire song is divided up into windows of some fraction of a second.
   [image: The orig signal]
2. For each window, a [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) or some equivalent transform the audio signal from the time to frequency domain.
   [image: a window and the transformed version of it]
3. The transformed signal is mirrored radially around the origin, where the "fatness" of each circle could correspond to "how tall the respective hump is" in the frequency graph. 
   [image: radial mirroring]

So, to make the animation "smooth" one would probably have at least 10 windows a second. Hope that helps. All images are own work.

Comment: That gives me something to search for. Thank you!